# SSIS scheduler has access but job failed

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I have question regarding SSIS. I have csv source files dumped at server xyz, and I have developed package. Now I want to deploy it to SQL Server box (server pqr) to run via job scheduler.

My question is are those files need to be present on the SQL Server box? Or account which runs job scheduler should be given access to location of file path mentioned in conn. manager of pkg?

I am newbee to ssis..

Thanks Regards,
Chaitanya

Answer (score 0):

Account that the Job Scheduler is running from should have appropriate access to folder (local or network) with csv files. Path to CSV files should be successfully resolved from the Job Scheduler location: `C:\temp\test.csv` or `\\servername\sharename\test.csv`.

If you've tried and job failed, please provide the error message.